# Web pages cannot be found when using Cassini

Tags: cassini, webdev.webserver

I have had trouble getting web pages to load within Cassini for about a week now.

I'm able to open a telnet session to the server - assuming I'm hosting on port 8101, typing `telnet localhost 8101` results in opening a connection.  I can simply type `GET` and eventually get back a response:

```
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Server: ASP.NET Development Server/9.0.0.0
Date: Thu, 09 Apr 2009 18:45:37 GMT
Content-Length: 1208
Connection: Close
```

(Actual HTML omitted for brevity. Suffice to say it's a web page saying "Bad Request".)

I've updated my hosts file after discovering an Windows Update messed with it.  It has exactly two non-comment lines:

```
::1             localhost
127.0.0.1       localhost
```

I've tried using Fiddler to monitor traffic and get "Target machine actively refused the request."

My firewall is turned off (as much as the Domain policy will allow, anyway).  I'm running Vista x64 and have IIS 7 installed, and can simply navigate to http://localhost/ and pull up the IIS7 welcome page easily.  If I choose to host the web project inside of IIS, it works (except for a couple custom HTTP modules that haven't been updated to work in IIS7, so that's not permanent).

Any other ideas?

EDIT: Tried using FireFox - get this in the address bar:

http://localhost:8080/Error.aspx?k=7b85a233-0459-47ab-9414-20c94350ee0e&

Contents of the page are:

Redirect Loop

Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never complete.

The browser has stopped trying to retrieve the requested item. The site is redirecting the request in a way that will never complete.

Comment: Turns out this was entirely my website - I had some configuration errors from external components.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you have a custom error page called "Error.aspx", but that page itself throws an error which causes another redirect to "Error.aspx" so the browser gets stuck in a redirect loop.  In IE, you'll just see it keep working but never load anything.  It sounds like Firefox detected the problem.

If you can telnet to the port then it's not a firewall problem.

I don't think the Fiddler problem is related.

Comment: You are correct - I removed the customErrors tag from my web.config.  However, it looks like I'm continually making several requests - the same output from FireFox happens.

Loading a different website seems to work OK - looks like it's just my website. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!